# How do you access mixin methods for Django models when doing a South datamigration?

Tags: python, django, mixins, django-south, data-migration

My Django models have a mixin that provides a `to_json` method:

```
class Tile(models.Model, SerializableMixin):
    flooring = models.ForeignKey('Flooring', related_name='tiles')
    ...
```

How do I access it in my data migration?

```
class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        tiles = orm.Tile.objects.filter(flooring__name="white")
        for tile in tiles:
            tile.cache = tile.to_json() # AttributeError, no attribute to_json
            tile.save(update_fields=['cache'])
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to cast the orm model as an instance of my model, performed the operations requiring the mixin & saved the results to the orm model.

```
from apps.flooring.models import Tile

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        tiles = orm.Tile.objects.filter(flooring__name="white")
        for tile in tiles:
            # Convert orm.Tile into Tile model to access serialization mixin
            t = Tile(**{k:v for (k,v) in t.__dict__.iteritems() if not k.startswith('_')})

            # update the orm.Tile model with new cache
            tile.cache = t.to_json()
            tile.save(update_fields=['cache'])
```

Comment: I answered my own question because there were no relevant questions regarding django model mixins and South. South encourages you to use the orm model's, which proved to be a misdirection in order to get the task done.  If you have a better or more generalized answer, please contribute and i'll give you the bounty!